# Looking for single exact word within string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to find a single exact word within a large string.

I have tried the below:

```py
for word in words:
    if word in strings:
        best.append("The word " + word + " The Sentence " + strings)
    else:
        pass
```

This seemed to work at first until tried with a larger set of words in a much larger string and was getting partial matches. As an example if the word is "me" it would pass "message" off as being found.

Is there a way of searching for exactly "me"?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set boundaries in order to find complete word. I'd go to regex. Something like:

```
re.search(r'\b' + word_to_find + r'\b')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string into words and then perform the `in` operation, making sure you strip the words in the list and the string of any trailing whitespaces

```
import string

def find_words(words, s):
    best = []

    #Strip extra whitespaces if any around the word and make them all lowercase
    modified_words = [word.strip().lower() for word in words]

    #Strip away punctuations from string, and make it lower
    modified_s = s.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
    words_list = [word.strip().lower() for word in modified_s.lower().split()]

    #Iterate through the list
    for idx, word in enumerate(modified_words):
        #If word is found in lit of words, append to result
        if word in words_list:
            best.append("The word " + words[idx] + " The Sentence " + s)

    return best

print(find_words(['me', 'message'], 'I me myself'))
print(find_words(['   me    ', 'message'], 'I me myself'))
print(find_words(['me', 'message'], 'I    me    myself'))
print(find_words(['me', 'message'], 'I am me.'))
print(find_words(['me', 'message'], 'I am ME.'))
print(find_words(['Me', 'message'], 'I am ME.'))
```

The output will be

```
['The word me The Sentence I me myself']
['The word    me     The Sentence I me myself']
['The word me The Sentence I    me    myself']
['The word me The Sentence I am me.']
['The word me The Sentence I am ME.']
['The word Me The Sentence I am ME.']
```

Comment: @thebjorn Fixed it, check if it makes sense now and looks correct and consider upvoting if it does :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use regex to find the word exactly.  \\b means boundary like space or punctuation marks.

```
for word in words:
    if len(re.findall("\\b" + word + "\\b", strings)) > 0:
        best.append("The word " + word + " The Sentence " + strings)
    else:
        pass
```

The double backslashes are due to a `'\b'` character being the backspace control sequence. [Source](https://developmentality.wordpress.com/2011/09/22/python-gotcha-word-boundaries-in-regular-expressions/)

Answer (score 0):

You could include the surrounding spaces in the if statement.

```
for word in words:
    if f' {word} ' in strings:
        best.append("The word " + word + " The Sentence " + strings)
    else:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

To make sure you don't detect words inside words that they are contained within (like "me" in "message" or "flame") is to add spaces before and after the words in the detection. The easiest way of doing this is to replace

```
if word in strings:
```

with

```
if " "+word+" " in strings:
```

Hope this helps! -Theo

Comment: Note that this will fail to find words at the beginning or end of a line and words immediately followed by punctuation.

Comment: @blubberdiblub true, it would need to be a little more complex (perhaps checking if characters before and after word's position in string aren't letters?)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set boundaries for your search, `\b` is the boundary character.

```
import re

string = 'youyou message me me me me me'
print(re.findall(r'\bme\b', string))
```

The string has `message` and `me`, we only need `me` explicitly. So added boundaries in my search expression. The result is below -

```
['me', 'me', 'me', 'me', 'me']
```

Got all the me(s), but not the `message` which also has a `me` in it.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the rest of the code, the best I could suggest is using == to get a direct match, so for example

```
a = 0
list = ["Me","Hello","Message"]
b = len(list)
i = input("What do you want to find?")
for d in range(b):
    if list[a] == i:
        print("Found a match")
    else:
        a = a+1
```